# Content Description in Multi Language

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

how I can add support of multi-language for content description. I am developing a kiosk app where I want to take confirmation from users for the language they want to have for accessibility.
I had tried the below code but it only speaks content in one language.

```
fun wrapTextInLocaleSpan(
            originalText: CharSequence, loc: LocaleList): SpannableStringBuilder {
        val myLocaleBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(originalText)
        myLocaleBuilder.setSpan(LocaleSpan(loc), 0,
                originalText.length - 1, 0)
        return myLocaleBuilder
    }
```

What could be best solution for supporting content description in multiple language ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you questions, I think that you misunderstand the purpose of [LocaleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LocaleSpan). This span will not do the translation for you, but just permits the developer to identify a part of a string the may be in another language from the rest of the string. There is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-FcOX6ErdI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9Gq6FEnSXClhYkWAStbwlC) from Google I/O '18 that explains this starting at time mark 5:16.

You should take a look at [Localize your app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-FcOX6ErdI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9Gq6FEnSXClhYkWAStbwlC) on how to present different translations for strings. You should also take a look at [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).